# numericUpDown.._ValueChanged pass as an argument

Tags: c#

I am doing an application which involves 20x NumericUpDown controls.
Some of them are password protected and in order to avoid double coding, I have a function called PasswordProtected.
Basically, I am showing a label indicating that the control is password protected, disable the trigger event and update the value of the control to 0.

However, I have a difficulty to pass ***numericUpDown13_ValueChanged*** as an argument in the PasswordProtected function.

```
private void PasswordProtected(NumericUpDown x)
{
    label68.Visible = true;
    label68.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    label68.Visible = false;

    x.ValueChanged -= numericUpDown13_ValueChanged;
    x.Value = 0;
    x.Refresh();
    x.ValueChanged += numericUpDown13_ValueChanged;
}
```

Comment: Can't understand what you are trying to do?
Events  are by default PUBLIC in c#. So why do you need to pass it as an argument to the method in the same class

Comment: I created the Password Protected function in order not to double code. I do not want to write the last four lines for every numericUpDown control. I have 20 in total.

Comment: The argument type needs to be *EventHandler*.  This approach seems highly unwise.  Beyond simply checking if it is "password protected" in the event handler, consider the Enabled property instead.